# upload file to dropbox programmatically

Tags: java, rest, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a file to dropbox programmatically. Basically file can be uploaded through dropbox api. 
But the question is how could I upload it by java rest based web service. The program to get the file is:

```
@Path("/file")
public class UploadFile {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

        Stringfilename = fileDetail.getFileName();
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

its good to have any links which describe about this topic.